# Let $X$ be a random variable with exponential distribution with $\lambda$ parameter. Find the CDF of random variable $Y= \lfloor X \rfloor$

Tags: probability

I want to find CDF of $Y$ by integration of PDF. There is a theorem, which gives us the next statement:
If $X$ is a continuous random variable with a density function $f_X$, and $g$ is a strictly increasing and differentiable function from $R$ into $R$, then $Y=g(X)$ has density function

> $f_{Y}(y)=f_{X}(g^{-1}(x))\frac{d}{dx}[g^{-1}(x)]$

where $g^{-1}$ is inverse function of $g$.

Here is the problem: Floor function has no inverse function, and I don`t know what to do.
Really hope for your help.

Comment: You use the fact that $\{Y = k\} = \{X \in [k, k + 1)\}.$

Comment: From the bottom of my heart, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$
P(Y=k) = P(k \leq X\lt k+1 ) = P(X\geq k) - P(X\geq k+1) = e^{-\lambda k}-e^{-\lambda(k+1)} 
$$
So
$$
P(Y=k) = e^{-\lambda k}
(1-e^{-1})$$
for $k\geq 0$. It follows that $Y$ is geometrically distributed.